# In Flutter how to print html from desktop

Tags: flutter

I am trying to print html using printing package `import 'package:printing/printing.dart';`. When I click on button which calls function printFile print dialog opens but nothing gets printed. I even try to save as pdf nothing happens. Is there anything more I need to add.

> ════════ Exception caught by printing ══════════════════════════════════════════ The following MissingPluginException was thrown while generating a PDF: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method convertHtml on channel net.nfet.printing)

```
  Future<void> printFile() async {

      await Printing.layoutPdf(
          onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => await Printing.convertHtml(
                format: format,
                html: '<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>',
              ));
    }
```

Full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Print Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Print Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await Printing.layoutPdf(
              onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async =>
                  await Printing.convertHtml(
                format: format,
                html: '<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>',
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Print HTML'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what platform are you on?

Comment: so MissingPluginException indicates that this is a platform specific error. and browsing through the source code, I can see that `convertHtml` is indeed not implemented on linux.